# Area of Generalized Koch Snowflake

Tags: geometry, fractals, polygons

I asked on the Math Stack Exchange [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3223258/area-of-generalized-koch-snowflake) how I could find the area of a "generalized Koch snowflake". An $n$th generalized Koch snowflake, in my case, is formed almost the same as the Koch snowflake - but instead of starting with an equilateral triangle, the start is a regular $n$-gon and the next iteration is formed by placing a regular $n$-gon with a side length $1/3$ of the previous side length on each side of the previous iteration.

How can I find or at least approximate this area given $n$ and the starting side length? I think maybe using polygons is the way to go, but I am new to Mathematica and don't really know how to use them.

Comment: It might be possible to do this with `GeometricScene`, although I haven't put in the time to create it. Perhaps something useful to be gleaned at [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/197697/how-to-do-this-padovan-spiral-using-mathematica/197725#197725) (and the question in general for other methods of generating scenes)

Comment: You may also find [`KochCurve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/KochCurve.html) interesting, and there are many [Demonstrations](https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/search.html?query=koch) relating to Koch curves and snowflakes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

---

Here is a start. **KochCurve** transforms a unit vector `{{0,0},{0,1}}`. This unit vector can be geometrically transformed via **FindGeometricTransform** into any polygon side. So given a side of a polygon you 1st **FindGeometricTransform** of unit vector into it and then transform with it **KochCurve**. The following function can transform any line into **KochCurve**:

```
ClearAll[lineKoch];
lineKoch[n_][vec_]:=
Last[FindGeometricTransform[vec,{{0,0},{1,0}}]][
ReflectionTransform[{0,1}][First[KochCurve[n]]]]
```

And the following function using **lineKoch** will transform any set of polygon vertex points into a n-Koch **MeshRegion**:

```
ClearAll[polyKoch];
polyKoch[n_][pt_]:=
MeshRegion[#,Polygon[Range[Length[#]]]]&@
Flatten[lineKoch[n]/@Partition[pt,2,1,1],1]
```

You need **MeshRegion** because **Area** or **RegionMeasure** can get the approximate area. You can see it at work, by applying it to some random point-sets:

```
Labeled[#,Area[#]]&[polyKoch[4][#]]&/@
Table[(#[[Last[FindShortestTour[#]]]]&@
RandomReal[1,{RandomInteger[{3,7}],2}]),10]
```

which will produce the image at the top of this post. You can also design an interactive app to change your polygons:

```
Manipulate[
Column[{Area[#],Show[#,PlotRange->2]}]&@polyKoch[n][pt],
{{n,2},Range[2,5]},
{{pt,CirclePoints[3]},Locator,LocatorAutoCreate->True}]
```

[image]

### UPDATE: other Koch shapes

To change Koch substitution shape use proper syntax of **KochCurve** function:

```
shape={{1,0},{1,90°},{1,-90°},{2,-90°},{1,90°},{1,90°},{1,-90°}};

lineKoch[n_][vec_]:=
Last[FindGeometricTransform[vec,{{0,0},{1,0}}]][
ReflectionTransform[{0,1}][First[KochCurve[n,shape]]]]

polyKoch[n_][pt_]:=
MeshRegion[#,Polygon[Range[Length[#]]]]&@
Flatten[lineKoch[n]/@Partition[pt,2,1,1],1]

Labeled[#,Area[#]]&[polyKoch[4][#]]&/@
Table[(#[[Last[FindShortestTour[#]]]]&@
RandomReal[1,{RandomInteger[{3,7}],2}]),10]
```

[image]

Comment: How can I change it from adding triangles to adding other polygons?

Comment: @automaticallyGenerated I do not understand your question. In this post you see demos with arbitrary polygons. What do you mean?

Comment: I see that it starts off with arbitrary polygons, but how can I change it so that it adds a square/regular pentagon, hexagon, etc in the middle of each side instead of an equilateral triangle? Sorry if this is a basic question - I'm new to Mathematica.

Comment: @automaticallyGenerated I added example at the end. Please look through examples in docs on [KochCurve](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/KochCurve.html) --- there is syntax of this function to make arbitrary-shape replacements .